# Different Cell with different label colour in UITableView using array

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to make a UITable that the Text lable in each cell is different according to the the code.

I am using NSArray to build the table. May I know how to modify this code so that i can specific the items with specific colour text?

Here are the code.

```
candyArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                  [Candy candyOfCategory:@"chocolate" name:@"chocolate bar\n 230-239"],
                  [Candy candyOfCategory:@"chocolate" name:@"chocolate chip"],
                  [Candy candyOfCategory:@"chocolate" name:@"dark chocolate"],
                  [Candy candyOfCategory:@"hard" name:@"lollipop"],
                  [Candy candyOfCategory:@"hard" name:@"candy cane"],
                  [Candy candyOfCategory:@"hard" name:@"jaw breaker"],
                  [Candy candyOfCategory:@"other" name:@"caramel"],
                  [Candy candyOfCategory:@"other" name:@"sour chew"],
                  [Candy candyOfCategory:@"other" name:@"peanut butter cup"],
                  [Candy candyOfCategory:@"other" name:@"gummi bear"], nil];
  // Initialize the filteredCandyArray with a capacity equal to the candyArray's capacity
    filteredCandyArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[candyArray count]];

    // Reload the table
    [[self tableView] reloadData];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below tableView delegate method and write the conditional code inside this method to assign specific color values to label's background color.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   ....


}
```

Inside this method you can check the value in `candyArray` by using below line and then assign the specific color.

```
[candyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
```

For setting a color use `UIColor` class:

```
[UIColor redColor] //like for red as you asked
[UIColor colorWithRed:  green: blue: alpha:] // for custom colors
```

Comment: Could you please further include the code for changing the colour? say the first row is red colour in text? Many Thanks

Comment: Updated my answer for setting a specific color. See UIColor and UITableView documentation for more insight

Answer (score 2):

I would implement the cell like this:

```
@interface CandyCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic,strong) Candy *candy;

@end
```

UI changes should occur when the **candy** property is set (still inside **CandyCell**)...

```
-(void)setCandy:(Candy*)candy
{
    _candy = candy;

    //Update UI here (e.g change color of the cell)
}
```

This can help keeping your UITableView delegate as slim as possibile.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self.tableView registerClass:[CandyCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([CandyCell class])];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CandyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([CandyCell class])];

    cell.candy = self.candies[indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```